# Semantic Mediawiki - Passing a variable to a template

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I have the result of a semantic query. For one of the properties, a comma separated list, I want to separate each item and pass it as a parameter to a template. However, I am struggling to find a way to do this.

For example;

Query:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Something]] [[Has title::Somethingelse]]
| mainlabel=-
| ?Has property
| link=none
| format=template
| template=plainText
}}
```

The plainText template will have the result, which is a comma separated list. Now, from the plainText template I would like to separate the comma separated list and put each value as a parameter into another template.

I have tried using `{{#arraydefine:key|values|delimiter|options}}` but when I pass `{{#arrayindex:key|0}}` to the template, the value is not passed. The whole array is passed separated by 0. I have also tried using `{{#vardefine:` etc but this also does not pass the variable.

My question boils down to, how to pass a variable to a template?

Thanks,

Comment: It's useful if you post `Template:plainText` as well as the other template which it calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separation needs to be done in the template.
If you use anonymous args like in
http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Query_output_demo

Your params can be fetched with defaults like this:

```
{{{1|param1default}}} {{{2|param2default}}} ...
```

Now one of your params is a comma separated list. You might want to use the

```
#explode
```

parser function to get to the different parts of the CSV. Lets assume the second
parameter has your csv then:

```
{{#explode:{{{2}}}|;|0}}
{{#explode:{{{2}}}|;|1}}
...
```

will provide the fields.

For this to work you need the extension

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions##explode

and to enable it according to the instructions there.